# Yii2 apply parameters to DB sort

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2

I have the following search function in my BlogPostSearch ActiveRecord:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = BlogPost::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
      'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
          'publishDate' => [
            'asc' => ['(CASE state 
                          WHEN '.static::STATE_ONLINE.' THEN published_at
                          WHEN '.static::STATE_OFFLINE.' THEN updated_at
                        END)' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['(CASE state 
                           WHEN '.static::STATE_ONLINE.' THEN published_at
                           WHEN '.static::STATE_OFFLINE.' THEN updated_at
                         END)' => SORT_DESC],
            'default' => SORT_DESC
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

But part of my soul dies every time I concatenate a parameter into SQL. Is it possible to bind variables in here?

Something like:

```
...
'asc' => [
  'expression'=> [
     '(CASE state 
         WHEN :online THEN published_at
         WHEN :offline THEN updated_at
       END)' => SORT_ASC
  ],
  'params' => [
    'online' => static::STATE_ONLINE,
    'offline' => static::STATE_OFFLINE,
  ],
], 
...
```

Comment: "But part of my soul dies every time I concatenate a parameter into SQL." why ?   .. you are concatenate CONSTANT ...

Comment: True, but I may well need to bind in a variable soon! Plus, I'd still rather bind if possible, for consistency and added peace of mind.